# concat fields that have a duplicate key in common and remove those dupes leaving one

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates, concatenation, mysql-workbench

This is bugging me for the last week now, and with basic knowledge i simply can't get to to a solution that brings us where we need to be. I've searched on updateing, group_concat, concat, joins, but i cant get the result we need.

The problem is as follows:

we have 2 columns that we work with to get to one result we need:

The DB we're working on:

```
+------------------------------------+-------------+  
| id                                 | value       |  
+------------------------------------+-------------+  
|  D44172cb5c086c19a4c0286270916bc52 | A           |  
|  D44172cb5c086c19a4c0286270916bc52 | C           |  
|  D44172cb5c086c19a4c0286270916bc52 | B           |  
|  D87d93570cbc9a3edc18601e0aff6e261 | D           |  
|  D87d93570cbc9a3edc18601e0aff6e261 | A           |
|  D87d93570cbc9a3edc18601e0aff6e261 | F           |
+------------------------------------+-------------+
```

What we expect to get:

```
 +-------------------------------------+-------------+  
 | id                                  | value       |  
 +-------------------------------------+-------------+  
 |  D44172cb5c086c19a4c0286270916bc52  | A|C|B       |  
 |  D87d93570cbc9a3edc18601e0aff6e261  | D|A|F       |  
 +-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

we're currently using a SELECT command that works and is giving the data as expected in a temporary(since we're only selecting) column named valuenew:

```
SELECT * GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '|') AS valuenew FROM db.table GROUP BY id ;
```

How do we make a (`UPDATE` or `DELETE`) query that deletes the duplicates, after it concatenated the needed values? Because, using `GROUP_CONCAT` the returned number of rows will be less than the actual rows present.

We need to combine the concatenated values in a later stage with other columns so the  rows need to be equal to the returned rows.

**SOLUTION**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` 
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`value` SEPARATOR '|') AS `values`
FROM `db`.`table` 
GROUP BY `id`;

TRUNCATE TABLE `db`.`table`;

UPDATE `temp` SET value = values;
ALTER TABLE `temp` DROP COLUMN values;

INSERT INTO `db`.`table`([all column titles here])
SELECT * 
FROM `db`.`temp`
;

DROP TABLE `db`.`temp`;
```

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, there are way more questions whose best answer involves **undoing** this kind of thing.

Comment: don't denormalize, unless you're 100% permanently irrevocably totally SURE that you'll never ever have to deal with the component values as individual values again.

Comment: If you don't want to have to write `GROUP_CONCAT()` in all your queries, define a `VIEW` that does it.

Comment: @MarcB We dont need the data as it once was, even if we did we could re-invoke a load data infile to restore all tables as they were. We need it as described to use it further in the process.
@Barmar it's not about not wanting to use `GROUP_CONCAT` it's about using a query that will also delete the duplicate rows it extracted the concatenated values from.

Comment: @RkdL Do you have a unique ID column in the table? If you really want to do this, you need a consistent way of deciding which row to put the combined values into and which ones should be deleted. That needs another column to distinguish the original rows in each group.

Comment: @RkdL But if you use a view that does the group concat, you don't need to delete anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must, this is probably the most direct way of doing it.

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`temp`
SELECT `id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`value` SEPARATOR '|') AS `value`
FROM `db`.`table` 
GROUP BY `id`;

TRUNCATE TABLE db.table;

INSERT INTO `db`.`table`(`id`, `value`)
SELECT `id`, `value` 
FROM `db`.`temp`
;

DROP TABLE `db`.`temp`
```

Of course, if there are other fields, you'll have to account for them appropriately to prevent data loss. *You could also make the `temp` table a true `TEMPORARY` table, but if you lose connection between the truncate and the re-insert you'd lose all data.*

Edit: Also make sure the `value` field can hold the longest GROUP_CONCAT() result.

Comment: We still need the remaining values, just not the rows that contain duplicate identifiers.  The actual table consists of 24 columns of info with these somewhere in between.

Comment: @RkdL You can still use this solution, just add all the other columns to the temp table.

Comment: I am trying to get this solution to work but again my knowledge ran out at the following. The first `SELECT` gives me a duplicate column name error, changing the name copies the extra column to the temp table, and can't copy that back since it didn't exist in the `table` table. Can i somehow overwrite or `update` the existing "value" column with the new values created?

Comment: It's done. i added 2 lines just after `truncate`. `UPDATE `temp` SET value = values;
ALTER TABLE `temp` DROP COLUMN values;`

Comment: @RkdL just so you know, the reason you had issues was because you used `*` instead of specifying the fields; also, if the fields are specified, you can avoid the need for the `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN` statement.

Comment: Thank you , much appreciated coming back to me about it. I'll be sure to try it.

Comment: @RkdL The downside is if you add another column, these queries may break; the upside is, if you add another column, it is probably best that the queries break to force reexamining whether they are still appropriate (such as how to handle if/when there is more than one value found in the new field for the same id).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the table, create a view that produces the concatenated values.

```
CREATE VIEW yourtable_view
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value SEPARATOR '|') AS values
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id;
```

Then use this view in queries that need to use the denormalized values.

If you really need to do it your way, your table needs another column in each group that can be used to distinguish the rows, so we can update the first row in the group and delete the remaining ones; if you have an `auto_increment` column, it can be used. I'll call this `unique_id` below.

```
-- First add the concatenated values to the first row in each group
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT id, MIN(unique_id) AS first_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value SEPARATOR '|') AS newvalues
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.unique_id = t2.first_id
SET t1.value = t2.values;

-- Then delete all the remaining rows in each group
DELETE t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT id, MIN(unique_id) AS first_id
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.unique_id > t2.first_id;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5170b/1)

Comment: ultimately we want to use those values to join with other columns, for this reason the returned number of rows in the new values need to equal the total rows in our table. the only reason the duplicates are there is because they are provided that way to us. each row of let's say 5 rows is exactly the same except for the value column we need, so we wouldn't need the other 4 and it's blowing up the table for no reason at all. we're working in a 60k row table that we can reduce to 10k doing this. Interested in your thoughts on this.

Comment: Just don't come back asking how to search for individual values or how to add a new value without duplicating. Those are hard to do with delimited lists in SQL.

Comment: You should probably use comma as the separator, so you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to search for things.

Comment: For some reason we're getting an error code 1054 (unkown column `id`) while it's clearly present.
We do have an extra unique column we can use for the `unique_id`, covered that much.

Comment: Ihad some syntax errors, I've corrected it. See the working demo.

Comment: Joining values is working great. we've added an `AUTO INCREMENT` unique id column as you suggested. The `DELETE` statement however is running endlessly (using MySQL Workbench) , it seems to hang on something and i can't figure out why. We're so close and i can't thank you enough for what you've already managed to clear up for us.

Comment: Add an index on `(id, unique_id)`, I think that should speed up the join.

Comment: I think a facepalm is needed on this end. i didnt mention in my first question that the 'unique but duplicated values' are in fact not just `INTEGERS` i should've been more clear on that since indexing the column brought it to my attention. i edited my question to better reflect the problem and im sorry if this wasted more time than needed Barmar.

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference.